# Find Difference Rows between two Sheets after comparing their Codes in a Column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, reduce, difference

I am trying to find the `NEW` rows added to a `Data` Sheet by comparing its `Codes` located in a column, with the `Codes` located in a column of a `Database` Sheet. I am doing this by finding the difference between the 2 codes.

```
...
// Get Mappings array
let Maplist = shtMap.getRange(2, 1, r_Map - 1, 2).getValues();

// find new codes that have come in the Data sheet
let DataCodes = [...new Set(shtData.getRange(2, 1, r_Data - 1, 1).getValues().flat())];
let DatabaseCodes = [...new Set(shtDatabase.getRange(2, 2, r_Database - 1, 1).getValues().flat())];

let diff =[];
// ===> Below is the line I want to modify to incorporate all the logic given in my Notes section.
diff = DataCodes.reduce( (diff,x) => !DatabaseCodes.includes(x) ? [...diff, [x]] : diff, []);

// Map Emp name to diff Array ===> not working....getting error!
diff = diff.map(function(x, i , arr){
    if(arr.indexOf(x) == i){
        return [...diff, [arr[i][1]]);
    }
}, (Maplist));

// Add Data Validation to `Status` column
var Rng = shtDatabase.getRange(r_Database + 1, 7, diff.length -1, 1);
Rng.clearDataValidations().clearContent();
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList([`Open`,`Complete`], true).build();
Rng.setDataValidation(rule); // Update `Status` value
...
```

The above codes gives me the `Difference i.e. new Codes` that have come into `Database` Sheet. Is there a way to modify the above `Reduce function code` to pull in the `entire new rows`, so that the `diff Array` can then be appended to the end of the `Database` Sheet?

**Note:**

- Here the `Delivery Date` in `Database Sheet` refers to the `FinalDate` in `Data Sheet`. Can the above code be modified to take into account the mismatched column name, so that the `FinalDate` column values are placed exactly in the `Delivery Date` column?
- I need to also add a `DataValidation dropdown` containing values `Open,Complete` into the `Status Column` of `Database Sheet`, for each new row in `diff array`. How can the above code take into account Data Validation code?
- As you can see, the `matching columns` in `Database Sheet` are not contiguous and in same order of the `Data Sheet`, but spread across the Sheet. Can the code be modified to properly place each diff array value into their respective columns?
- Finally, i have to compare each`Owner` name in the `Database Sheet` with an `Mapping Sheet` Array (which contains the `Owner` name and it's corresponding `Emp` name), then match its corresponding `Emp` name and add this to the `Emp` column in `Database Sheet` accordingly.

**Reason:**

- I would like to do all this in memory and finally transfer this memory Array to `Database Sheet` in one go. Otherwise, repeatedly accessing (read/write) the Sheets takes a lot of time for the code to run, especially when the data is large. Is this possible with some consice code?

**Data Sheet:**
[image: Data Sheet]
**Database Sheet:**
[image: Database Sheet]
**Mapping Sheet**
[image: Mapping Sheet]

Here is the link to the [Sample File][4].

[4]:

**Edit:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DARGtbN8EyEKyF9ceuOusStvuPIXjUR_8OrqfhPxpNQ/edit?usp=sharing

@TheMaster, Here is the entire code written in the file:

```
function myTest(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const shtData = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const shtMap = ss.getSheetByName("Mapping");
  const shtDatabase = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

    // get Data Sheet unique list of Owners
  let r_Data = FindLastRow(shtData);
  let c_Data = FindLastColumn(shtData);
  let list = shtData.getRange(2, 4, r_Data - 1, 1).getValues();
  let Datalist = [...new Set(list.flat())];

  // get Mapping Sheet unique list of Owners
  r_Map = FindLastRow(shtMap);
  c_Map = FindLastColumn(shtMap);
  list = shtMap.getRange(2, 1, r_Map - 1, 1).getValues();
  let Maplist = [...new Set(list.flat())];
  
  // find new codes that have come in the Data sheet
  r_Database = FindLastRow(shtDatabase);
  c_Database = FindLastColumn(shtDatabase);
  let DataCodes = [...new Set(shtData.getRange(2, 1, r_Data - 1, 1).getValues().flat())];
  let DatabaseCodes = [...new Set(shtDatabase.getRange(2, 2, r_Database - 1, 1).getValues().flat())];
  
  // find the difference between the 2 arrays and append the new ones to Mapping Sheet, then sort.
  let diff = Datalist.reduce( (diff,x) => !Maplist.includes(x) ? [...diff, [x,'Unassigned']] : diff,[]);
  if(diff.length !== 0){
    shtMap.getRange(r_Map + 1, 1, diff.length, diff[0].length).setValues(diff);
  }

  // Sort the Mappings Sheet on 2nd column, then 1st column
  shtMap.getDataRange().offset(1, 0, shtMap.getDataRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  

//  diff =[];
  // ===> Below is the line I want to modify to incorporate all the logic given in my Notes section.
  diff = DataCodes.reduce( (diff,x) => !DatabaseCodes.includes(x) ? [...diff, [x]] : diff, []);


  // From Notes : Map Emp name to diff Array ===> not working....getting error!
  diff = diff.map( function(x, i, arr){
    if(arr.indexOf(x) == i){
      return [...diff, arr[1][i]];
    }
  }, (Maplist));
  
  // From Notes : Add Data Validation to `Status` column
  var Rng = shtDatabase.getRange(r_Database + 1, 7, diff.length -1, 1);
  Rng.clearDataValidations().clearContent();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList([`Open`,`Complete`], true).build();
  Rng.setDataValidation(rule); // Update `Status` value
}


function FindLastRow(sht) {
  return sht.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion().getLastRow();
};

function FindLastColumn(sht) {
  return sht.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion().getLastColumn();
};
```

**Edit:**
@Tanaike, i have updated the screenshots in the post as well as updated the spreadsheet also. for e.g. the Yellow rows in `Data` sheet are `new rows` and so need to be placed in the `Database` sheet correctly and also add Data validation in `Status` column, `Emp` name in `Emp` column (after matching `Owner` with Mapping Sheet). `FinalDate` column in `Data` sheet is the `Delivery Date` column in `Database` sheet.

The idea is to create a consice code that would create a single 2D array (which should include the datavalidation & Emp name), to place all the new data correctly in the `Database` sheet. I want to avoid writing data to sheet everytime for updating each columns in `Database` sheet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218741/discussion-on-question-by-sifar-find-difference-rows-between-two-sheets-after-co).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding the following sample script to the bottom of your `myTest()`?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
  var Rng = shtDatabase.getRange(r_Database + 1, 7, diff.length -1, 1);
  Rng.clearDataValidations().clearContent();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList([`Open`,`Complete`], true).build();
  Rng.setDataValidation(rule); // Update `Status` value
}
```

To:

```
  var Rng = shtDatabase.getRange(r_Database + 1, 7, diff.length -1, 1);
  Rng.clearDataValidations().clearContent();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList([`Open`,`Complete`], true).build();
  Rng.setDataValidation(rule); // Update `Status` value

  // I added below script.
  const mapObj = shtMap.getRange("A2:B" + shtMap.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, [a, b]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: b}), {});
  const existingIdsObj = shtDatabase.getRange("B2:B" + shtData.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, [b]) => Object.assign(o, {[b]: true}), {});
  const putValues = shtData.getRange("A2:G" + shtData.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((ar, [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) => {
    if (!existingIdsObj.hasOwnProperty(a)) ar.push([b, a, f, c, , , , d, e, , , g, , mapObj[d]]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  shtDatabase.getRange(shtDatabase.getLastRow() + 1, 1, putValues.length, putValues[0].length).setValues(putValues);
}
```

- In order to check the duplicated ID and put `Emp` value, I used the JSON objects of `mapObj` and `existingIdsObj`.